# Is there a way to get PyCharm to create a virtualenv for a project in a project when creating a project?

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv

I want my working areas to be self-contained and independent.  For this reason, I'd like to be able to set up a virtualenv inside a project directory and have the project use it as I'm creating the project.

Is this possible?

To answer my own question: yes sort of. Here's the procedure I came up with:

1. Select "Create New Project"
2. Select "Create VirtualEnv" from the interpreter menu.
3. Open a file browser to select the virtualenv location.
4. Browse to the directory to contain the new **project**.
5. Create a new directory. This will be the project directory.
6. Create a new directory for the virtialenv
7. Click OK
8. Select the parent of the virtualenv as the project directory.
9. Click Create
10. PyCharm complains that the directory isn't empty and offers to use existing sources.
11. Select "No".

At that point, there's a new project containing the virtualenv.

I guess this isn't too bad, but I wonder if there's a better way.

Answer (score 0):

> Click /help/img/idea/2016.3/cogwheel_framed.png next to the Project
>   Interpreter field, and choose the option Create VirtualEnv. Create
>   Virtual Environment dialog box opens. In the Create Virtual
>   Environment dialog box, do the following: In the Name field, type the
>   name of the new virtual environment, or accept the suggested default
>   name. In the Location field, specify the target directory, where the
>   new virtual environment will be created, or accept the suggested
>   default location. From Base interpreter drop-down list, select one of
>   the configured Python interpreters, which will be used as the base for
>   the new virtual environment.

see link [pycharm documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/creating-virtual-environment.html)

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with that. But either either that has to be done before creating the project, or after the project is created.  If before, then it ends up outside the project directory. If after then dependencies will get installed (or install attempted) before the virtual environment can be created,